# Where did an additional `android-support-v7-appcompat` project come from in my workspace? Which one to use?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have the latest Android Support library with `Rev 22.2.1`. I included the AppCompat v7 library from my SDK it in my workspace by following the guideline at the Android developer guides. Initially it included the project named `appcompat_v7` in my project explorer. So far so good.

Then after creating a few projects and including a few other libraries like `recyclerview` and `cardview` and some third party library projects, **I now notice two projects named `appcompat_v7` and `android-support-v7-appcompat` in my project explorer.**

This wouldn't bother me but now whenever I want to add the appcompat v7 library in my project, I am given both the options, and I get confused about which one to use. **So the question is that where did `android-support-v7-appcompat` come from, and which one should I use when I want to include the v7 library in a project (also provided that the project is also using another third party library project).**

[image]

Comment: When you import a library in eclipse you can choose the name. Morover, it is time to switch to Android Studio.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti It's not about the name but a new library project appearing mysteriously in my workspace, and then I don't know which one to use. About Android Studio, my laptop is too slow for it. When I run AS, everything starts hanging, and yes I have read and applied the blogs talking about speeding it up. Google should send me a new computer before stopping support for Eclipse.

Comment: I don't know what it is the second library. Remove them and import again the appcompat. When you import the library, you can see the name in the IDE.In this way you will be sure about the library to use.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti It's the `appcompat_v7` one which I included from my SDK. I have tried this tons of times and with different workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Select Second Option AppCompat_v7

Comment: That would anwer 50% of the question if you said "why"! But thank you for answering, I appreciate your answer. Upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat_v7 is actually Android Support library which is introduced recently and is required for **App**lication **Compat**ibility for older versions of Android.

Please select second library (AppCompat_v7) as mentioned in above comment.

You can also read below articles if you need more info:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html